# CSS Class or ID named 404

Tags: css

I've been developing a site and recently came across that naming a css class or id '404' *(with no quotes of course)* will not display any styling for the element named 404.

I did not know this until I had to well, create a 404 page and named the element accordingly.
*(I'm actually surprised I haven't run into this before.)*

**Is there and specific reason behind this?**
Excuse my ignorance if it's something simply obvious, been up for 48 hours coding and was flipping out at first because I thought my browser wasn't refreshing my css file properly! :P

Anyway I've simply renamed the element and the styling works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`404` is not a valid identifier. You basically have to start an identifier by a letter or an underscore (or maybe some other characters such as `$` and `-`).

Please also not that it doesn't have anything to do with HTML4/5 .. it's a CSS rule. CSS identifiers must be conform to the following rules (including in [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation)) :

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed
>   by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any
>   ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance,
>   the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F". Note
>   that Unicode is code-by-code equivalent to ISO 10646 (see [UNICODE]
>   and [ISO10646]).
>
> In CSS 2.1, a backslash () character can indicate one of three types
>   of character escape. Inside a CSS comment, a backslash stands for
>   itself, and if a backslash is immediately followed by the end of the
>   style sheet, it also stands for itself (i.e., a DELIM token).

Comment: I figured, I should probably go get some rest now lol

Comment: @JMXI If this answer is one you were looking for, you can mark it as accepted by clicking on the left icon ; )

Answer (score 1):

In the html 4 standard, ids and classes may not begin with a digit. You might want to take a closer look at the spec for that. Html 5 however removed most of the existing restrictions. To make use if this you have to change your doctype to:

```
<!doctype html>
```

I would generally advise to use this doctype, it save to use, clean and futureproof.

CSS also restricts the selector, but you can escape that with it's Unicode symbol:

```
.\34 04{/*styles for your 404 class*/}
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/an9Bw/)**